# How to use large Stage in Scratch

Tags: wallpaper, stage, mit-scratch

I have to write a simple program in Scratch.

It is a tourist guide of the city of my Institute (Urbino, Italy). This is the map in Openstreetmap.org:

[image: Urbino, Italy]

Scratch has a fixed size for the Stage of **480x360**.

**QUESTION**: There is a way to use a more large Stage without charging thousand of Stages?

Comment: Unfortunately, Scratch's stage size is fixed, so there really isn't much you can do. If you want to get really crazy, you could create a [Scratch modification](https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Scratch_Modification) with a larger stage, but that would be quite the undertaking. Otherwise, I'd recommend making your project usable on the smaller stage, perhaps by adding zooming or scrolling (or both).

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52241482/10136347)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the resolution of the stage in MIT Scratch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52241482/how-to-change-the-resolution-of-the-stage-in-mit-scratch)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you right, you need a larger stage to see more details of the map, right?

You can try to import the bitmap image in the vector editor, and add an ability to zoom into the map ([Example for Zoom](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/39998922/)).

To find out more about using vector images in Scratch, visit this link:
https://en.scratch-wiki.info/wiki/Vector_Graphics

Comment: Good idea to use the vector image. Unfortunately, the image is resized during acquisition, and can not be used. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use a vector graphics program like InkScape to trace it and turn it into a vector image before you load it into Scratch. Only then will it retain its size and acuity.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make it scroll.
Have two variables, called "scrollX" and "scrollY".
Then show them and make them sliders.
(You might need to change their ranges.)

Then use this:

```
when greenFlag clicked
forever
  go to x:(scrollX) y:(scrollY)
end
```